# How do I read a file in the airflow cloud composer bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

To separate bigquery queries from the actual code I want to store the sql in a separate file and then read it from the python code. I have tried to add the file in the same bucket as the DAGs and also in a sub folder, but it seems like I can't read the file when it airflow is running my python script with the sql files.

What I want is this:

```
gs://my-bucket/dags -> store dags
gs://my-bucket/dags/sql -> store sql files
```

The sql files might be files that I need to read first to inject things that is not supported by the jinja templating.

Can I do the above?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do that's not supported by the Jinja templating?  Am I understanding correctly that you've created a Connection object to GCS but are getting some sort of error trying to access SQL files at the paths listed?

Comment: First of, quite new with airflow and composer. What I want to do is to dynamically set which xcom variable to read.

Comment: So I need to create a gcs connection? I just assumed that composer/airflow synced the gcs bucket with the disk that airflow have access to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cloud Composer mounts the GCS bucket using a FUSE driver from `gs://my-bucket` to `/home/airflow/gcs/`. This means that the `gs://my-bucket/dags` folder is available in the scheduler, web server, and workers at `/home/airflow/gcs/dags`.

Your DAGs should be able to read the SQL files from the `/home/airflow/gcs/dags/sql` directory.

Note: the `/home/airflow/gcs/data` directory is available on workers but not the webserver.

Comment: Awesome. Will try first thing tomorrow. Sounds like what I need.

Comment: I'm guessing a better approach is to use the `DAGS_FOLDER` env. variable.

Comment: another approach might be to use settings.DAGS_FOLDER , this way you can reference the dag folder so that you do not have to hardcode the path, in local test, this path can be different and settings.DAGS_FOLDER can help you