# Run a shell script file with Airflow on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: bash, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have several multi-purpose shell scripts stored in `.sh` files. My intention is to build a few Airflow DAGs on Cloud Composer that will leverage these scripts. The DAGs would be made mostly of BashOperators that call the scripts with specific arguments.

Here's a simple example, `greeter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, $1!"
```

I can run it locally like this:

```
bash greeter.sh world
> Hello, world!
```

Let's write a simple DAG:

```py
# import and define default_args

dag = DAG('bash_test',
          description='Running a local bash script',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='0,30 5-23 * * *',
          catchup=False,
          max_active_runs=1)

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_command',
    bash_command=f"bash greeter.sh world",
    dag=dag
)
```

But where to put the script `greeter.sh`? I tried putting it both in the `dags/` folder and the `data/` folder, at first level or nested within a `dependencies/` directory. I also tried writing the address as `./greeter.sh`. Pointless: I can never find the file.

I also tried using `sh` in place of `bash` and I get a different error: `sh: 0: Can't open greeter.sh`. But this error also appears when the file is not there, so it's the same issue. Same with any attempt to run `chmod +rx`.

How can I make my file available to Airflow?

Comment: does using `/full/path/to/greeter.sh` work? (just for our info, I have not experience with airflow). Good luck!

Comment: I am not sure what the full path is or how I could find it, the composer environment seems to be running in a Kubernetes Engine instance and I could not find a way to SSH into it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512411/how-do-i-read-a-file-in-the-airflow-cloud-composer-bucket#comment88063343_50515363) revealed the answer.

The address for the `dags_folder` is stored in the `DAGS_FOLDER` environment variable.

To get the right address for a script stored in `dags_folder/`:

```py
import os

DAGS_FOLDER = os.environ["DAGS_FOLDER"]
file = f"{DAGS_FOLDER}/greeter.sh"
```