# How can I write a file from a DAG to my composer cloud storage bucket?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512411/how-do-i-read-a-file-in-the-airflow-cloud-composer-bucket?noredirect=1&lq=1) to this question states that

"...the gs://my-bucket/dags folder is available in the scheduler, web server, and workers at /home/airflow/gcs/dags."

([which is supported by the newer docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/cloud-storage))

So I wrote a bash operator like this:

```
t1 = bash.BashOperator(
    task_id='my_test',
    bash_command="touch /home/airflow/gcs/data/test.txt",
    )
```

I thought by prefacing my file creation with the path specified in the answer it would write to the data folder in my cloud composer environment's associated storage account. Simiarly, `touch test.txt` also ran successfully but didn't actually create a file anywhere I can see it (I assume it's written to the worker's temp storage which is then deleted when the worker is shut down following execution of the DAG). I can't seem to persist any data from simple commands run through a DAG? Is it even possible to simply write out some files from a bash script running in Cloud Composer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to add the path to a new variable and pass the variable to the `bash_command`? It would be something like this
`command=”./home/airflow/gcs/data/test.txt”` and then passing it like `bash_command=command`.

Comment: Thanks, I will that for my next BashOperator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bizarrely, I needed to add a space at the end of the string containing the Bash command.

```
t1 = bash.BashOperator(
    task_id='my_test',
    bash_command="touch /home/airflow/gcs/data/test.txt ",
    )
```

The frustrating thing was the error said the path didn't exist so I went down a rabbit-hole mapping the directories of the Airflow worker until I was absolutely certain it did - then I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146934/how-to-run-bash-script-file-in-airflow/40147039). Although I didn't get the 'Jinja Template not Found Error' I should have got according to this [note](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614).